# Pxeboot Grub2 UEFI with very large initrd

Tags: linux, boot, memory, grub

I'm working on a project which requires that I PXEboot a very large initrd (1.3G) to a client, however when using grub2 via uefi I come across the error:

```
Can't allocate initrd
```

Which seems to indicate grub is trying to access beyond its address limit. 
...which is strange because the memory limit should be much higher on a 64-bit machine with 32GB of RAM.

PXE-ing a smaller image is not an option as NFSmounts are unreliable in my location. 
I'm not married to Grub2, but was unable to get syslinux.efi to boot after compiling from source.

Is there a way to force grub to take the big initrd?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem by making a Dracut image with livenet/network modules built in, and used a squashfs root.

Just a note that Dracut expect the SquashFS to be formatted in a certain way:
/LiveOS/rootfs.img
Where rootfs.img is an ext4 formatted filesystem containing the actual filesystem.

Comment: Can you add what your PXE menu option looks like, and explain why it worked?  I arrived at the same conclusion after contacting the Grub mailing list and got things working, but when I found this answer before that I didn't understand what it meant.

Comment: @Locane I used the following: label label
  kernel <kernel>
  append initrd=<initrd> root=live:http://SERVER/squashfs.img rd.driver.pre=loop rd.writable.fsimg=1

Comment: I meant to your answer haha.  For everyone else wondering.

Answer (score 1):

PXE transferring a 1.3GB initrd is just a bad design.

You do not need to relay on NFS. The typical approach is a 20/40 MB initrd with network support able to map SMB shares or just retrieve components by HTTP (wget/curl). This method is seen when installing discrete component distributions like Ubuntu Server or Live distros like Ubuntu desktop Live. In your case if you have everything in your initrd you should split it and convert it into a squashfs single file.

Unfortunately syslinux.efi 6.03 is still not 100% reliable and grub2 is not really friendly.

See here how [Serva](http://vercot.com/~serva/an/NonWindowsPXE3.html) PXE boots lot of Linux distros what will surely help you booting yours. (I'm related to Serva development)

Comment: Is there a guide somewhere on how to do this?  As a sysadmin newbie, I don't know where to begin creating a custom 40 meg initrd.  I have systems transferring a huge livecd around through PXE a lot - it would be great to figure out how to minimize that.

Comment: All the Linux distros have tools that help creating their own initrds; that's the starting point. e.g. Ubuntu's `initramfs-tools`.